# Display the current date in a mm/dd/yyyy format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime.now()

print "%s-%s-%s" % (current_time.month, current_time.day current_time.year,)
#Will print the current date in a mm/dd/yyyy format.

input()
```

The code above is meant to print out the current date in a `mm/dd/yyyy` format in a command prompt. So for example if this actually worked it would open up a command prompt window that printed out; for example the current date as im writing this like this: `8-5-2017`

I keep getting this error when trying to run the module that the closing " in "`%s-%s-%s`" that it's invalid syntax. Is python 3 using something different from this or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 15):

In python3, `print` statements require braces.

Furthermore, if you're looking to print the data, just use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
In [340]: print(current_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
Out[340]: '08/05/2017'
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that print required brackets. Too much time on code academy and not using the editor slipped me up on that.

Comment: If you don't want the month or day to have leading zeros then on Linux/Unix use `%-m/%-d/%Y`. For Windows use `%#m/%#d/%Y` .